# Why JFrameForm Item Showing Up In My Internal Frame Form Page Netbeans

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, frame

Sorry The Pictures On This Link Idk How To Make Its Shows Up

Main Menu Photo
[Main Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b54h4.png)

Internal Frame Form Photo
[Intenal Form Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUYom.png)

I Do Something Like This But Not Work Idk How To Do It Help Me??

```
private void siswaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
FormMurid Murid = new FormMurid();
jPanel1.add(Murid);
Murid.show();
Murid.toFront();
}
```

Thank For Helping

What Should I do To Make Sure The JFrameForm Label Is In Behind JInternalForm Not In Front Of It??